# How to ignore fields of POJO Objects to be added to the spring model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I have added **Spring Bean** as dependency into my **Domain Model (POJO)**:
My requirement is just to get Employee name while constructing POJO Objects from Spring **Map Bean**.
Spring Map Bean holds all the details of Employee for userId,
A side by question **Any other solution for this ?**
My POJO is as follows

```
@Configurable(dependencyCheck=true,preConstruction=true,autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME)
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class PostDetail {
    private Integer id;
    private String content;
    private Boolean isCommentable;
    private Boolean isActive;
//  @JsonIgnore
//  private MultipartFile [] postAttachments;

    private Integer posterId;
    private String posterName;
    private String postedDate;

//  @Autowired
    @Resource(name="userEmployeeDetailByUserId")
    private Map<Integer, UserEmployeeDetail> userEmployeeDetailByUserId;
//  private List<CommentDetail> commentDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    public PostDetail() {}
    @Autowired
    public PostDetail(Map<Integer, UserEmployeeDetail> userEmployeeDetailByUserId) {
        this.userEmployeeDetailByUserId = userEmployeeDetailByUserId;
    }
    public PostDetail(Integer id, String content, Boolean isCommentable, Boolean isActive, String log) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.isCommentable = isCommentable;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        if( log != null ) {
            String [] logDetails = log.split("##");
            this.posterId = Integer.valueOf( logDetails[2] );
            System.out.println(userEmployeeDetailByUserId +" : "+ this.posterId);
            this.posterName = userEmployeeDetailByUserId.get( this.posterId ).getEmployeeFirstAndLastName(); //logDetails[0];
            this.postedDate = logDetails[1];

        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("PostDetail [id=").append(id).append(", content=")
                .append(content).append(", isCommentable=")
                .append(isCommentable).append(", isActive=").append(isActive)
                .append(", posterId=").append(posterId).append(", posterName=")
                .append(posterName).append(", postedDate=").append(postedDate)
                .append(", userEmployeeDetailByUserId=")
                .append(userEmployeeDetailByUserId).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

When I'm adding My above mention POJO **PostDetail** into Spring's Model, My POJO is being added with it's all fields to Model. And I want to avoid/ignore some of its fields being added to Model.

I want something like `@JsonIgnore` so fields are avoided from being added.

Comment: You can use  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) at class level

Comment: I have not understood your problem completely. Do you want to add a single field into the json from the POJO, ignoring all the remaining fields?

Comment: I'am not dealing with `JSON` nor returning `JSON` from my controller method, but with Spring `Model`, while rendering/constructing JSP,